# Python trying to write. But only writes last value and not all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am scraping a webpage using selenium. And from that webpage there are multiple div's with the same class that I put in a list. And then try to receive some information out of it. This returns the following; `a\nb\nc\nd\n` (just `a b c d` but on other lines). And that then a couple of times. So I get the following list; `['a\nb\nc\nd\n', 'e\nf\ng\nh\n']` etc. etc. I have splitted these values, to make is json strings. So that returns **in a string**; `['["a", "b", "c", "d"]', '["e", "f", "g", "h"]']` This all works fine when printing it in my console. But now I want it to put every item in the list, so every json. into a text file on a new line. So I tried this;

```
    for snipe in snipes:
        with open('snipes.txt', 'w') as f:
            snipe = json.dumps(s, separators=(',',':'))
            print snipe
            f.write(snipe+"\n")
        f.close()
```

So printing `snipe` works all fine, it print all of the values. But when I check `snipes.txt` it only has the last value in the list. And not all of them on all seperate lines.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide input and output expected, along with what your actual program is returning.

Comment: put the for loop within the `with` statement, opposite from current way

Comment: `open('snipes.txt', 'w')`  kills existing file, and opens a blank one. use `'a'` - it is better to open once and write in a loop though - so switch `for` and `with` lines around.

Comment: Also, you don't need `f.close()` when using a `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are opening the file, writing one line, closing it, next loop, overwriting the file by writing to it again, etc. Please consider the following:

```
# always open the file before looping to keep it open
# using with will auto close the file when done
with open('snipes.txt', 'w') as f:
    # loop through and write everything
    for snipe in snipes:
        snipe = json.dumps(s, separators=(',',':'))
        print snipe
        f.write(snipe+"\n")
```